# IPv4 and UDP/TCP packets inside of ICMP packet?

Tags: ipv4, tcp, network, wireshark, icmp

A week ago, after opening wireshark, i was surprised by seing a storm of ICMP packets from different IP addresses. While deep analysing of thoses packets, i noticed that **those ICMP packets contains IPv4 headers and UDP/TCP headers.** It seems like port scanning.
I spent a lot of time searching of an answer of how this is possible but i didnt find anything. I know that there is an attack named ICMP tunneling but i dont think that there is some tunneling in this case.

[image: IPv4 & TCP over ICMP]

Here is some other pictures:

https://ibb.co/TvmZS6Y 
https://ibb.co/FnpsVVR 
https://ibb.co/rMqwgyv 
https://ibb.co/pZPXTgC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ICMP error message will contain the IP header and first 64 bits (eight octets) of the original data. See *[RFC 792, Internet Message Control Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792)*:

> Internet Header + 64 bits of Data Datagram
>
> The internet header plus the first 64 bits of the original datagram's
> data. This data is used by the host to match the message to the
> appropriate process. If a higher level protocol uses port numbers,
> they are assumed to be in the first 64 data bits of the original
> datagram's data.